# Prove or disprove that the set of critical values is nowhere dense.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $g:\mathbb R^{d}\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a non-negative, continuously differentiable function satisfying the following two conditions:

1. The set $\{x\in \mathbb R^d \ |\ \| \nabla g(x)\|<\eta\}$ is bounded in $\mathbb R^d$ for some $\eta>0$.
2. There exists a constant $L>0$ such that $\|\nabla g(x)- \nabla g(y)\|\le L\|x-y\|$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb R^d$.

Question: Denote by $\mathcal C= \{x\in \mathbb R^d \ |  \  \nabla g(x)=0\}$ the [critical set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics)) of $g$. Can we prove that the set $g(\mathcal C)$ of critical values of $g$ (here $g(\mathcal C)$ is the image of $\mathcal C$ under $g$) is [nowhere dense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_dense_set) in $\mathbb R$?

Note that we cannot directly use Sard's theorem here because we only guarantee first-order continuous differentiability.

Comment: Note that we cannot directly use Sard's theorem here because we only guarantee first-order continuous differentiability.